# How to display data (dynamic text) using wxPython GUI library?

Tags: python, wxpython

So far I've been using print statements, which work really well. I want to start using the GUI to display results but I can't find a way to do it.

It's a search program. It has to display the results every time the search button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Objectlistview](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/python/) is one of the ways of easily displaying list data in wxpython.